# No module named 'gdbm'

Tags: python3

I just finished installing python 3.5.1 on my Ubuntu, but am faced with this error message, regardless if I'm installing with Anaconda or with `apt-get`:

```
No module named 'gdbm'
```

that normally displays on my terminal. I have also tried installing `gdbm` using:

```
sudo apt-get install gdbm
```

but doesn't solve the problem. Can I get a help on how to fix this problem from anyone here?

Comment: Hi Asogwa, not sure about your latest comment below my answer; did you get it to work? Please let me know.

Comment: How are you installing? Are you doing it with Anaconda or some other way?

Comment: I am not yet able to install Anaconda because when ever I want to install Anaconda I get the same "error No module named 'gdbm'"

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. Anaconda is a package that contains Python3. So are you installing Anaconda or are you installing Python3 separately.

Comment: Am installing Anaconda

Comment: This might be a bug to report to the Anaconda people then... Have you tried other versions of Anaconda? Such as the one for Python 3.4?

Comment: yes, I have @Seanny123

Comment: Have you tried installing Python without Anaconda and just with `apt-get`?

Comment: Yes, I have @Seanny123

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Also, have you finished installing Python or are you trying to install Python. Your working has confused me a bit.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: No solution in this world works for me. :(

Answer (score 61):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-gdbm
```

helped me

Comment: Of course, the same pattern applies for python 3.6.

Comment: What to do in case of `Unable to locate package python3.6-gdbm`? I tried to add a new repository, but the initial error appears again.

Comment: and the same pattern for `python3.7-gdbm` for me

Comment: For python 3.6 use `sudo apt-get install python3.6-gdbm`

Answer (score 34):

In my case, if I tried running *any* command that doesn't exist in a bash shell I would get this gross error:

```
$ programthatdoesntexist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm', please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ImportError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

None of the answers above worked in my case. Although this problem has been solved, this might help someone. If you are still having this issue, maybe this will help:

I had installed python3.6 from the repository  `ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu` , and apparently that broke some things.

When tying to reinstall the packages `command-not-found python3-commandnotfound python3-gdbm python3-gdbm-dbg sessioninstaller`, I noticed that apt was pulling sources from here:

```
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-gdbm amd64 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2 [14.6 kB]
```

To fix the issue, I simply removed that repository:

```
sed -i ' s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list
```

And than re-ran this command (as root):

```
apt update ; apt purge python3-gdbm ; apt install command-not-found python3-commandnotfound python3-gdbm python3-gdbm-dbg sessioninstaller
```

Now, everything works again:

```
$ lol
No command 'lol' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sol' from package 'aisleriot' (main)
 Command 'col' from package 'bsdmainutils' (main)
lol: command not found
```

Comment: I just had the same on 16.04 LTS. I think looking at the timing of your answer a new update either in the jonathonf repo or standard repos has a conflict. Since I moved to pyenv for my Python  versions anyway, getting rid of the jonathonf repository is probably a good idea for me.

Comment: Thanks. Just a note that people might also notice the crash report app firing because `command-not-found` is failing.

Comment: Had the same problem, and this solution worked. At the same time, `python3.6 -m venv` was broken for me. Changing to the deadsnakes repository solved all my issues. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50197283/7599943

Comment: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6` fixed it for me (it reinstalled the necessary packages automatically).

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried installing the package `python3-gdbm`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gdbm
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but still giving me the same error message.

Comment: This is because there is no module named `gdbm` any more. Use `_gdbm`.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on version of python you recently installed, **ONE** of the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-gdbm
sudo apt-get install python3.6-gdbm
sudo apt-get install python3.7-gdbm
```

Comment: doesn't work for python 3.8

Answer (score 6):

I have python 3.6 install and working i have tried many things but

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-gdbm
```

This command worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and got it solved by:

```
sudo apt install python3-gdbm=3.5.1-1
dpkg -L python3-gdbm
```

running synaptic, for something else, displayed that python3-gdbm needed an update. I allowed synaptic to make the update and:
**Now I get the same issue back.**

When running above commands again I get as message, in the terminal, for the first command: The following packages will be DOWNGRADED : python3-gdbm.
After answering Y to the question if I want to continue, traceback works again.

So there is clearly something wrong (bug) in the latest version of python3-gdbm.

Comment: this worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install python3-django
```

helped me

Comment: Hi zxdc, you might want to explain your answer. Does installing django also install gdbm somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I had forgot to activate a Python virtual environment that was used with the command I was trying to run (The tx command in my case).

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to install the python-gdbm package for your version of python. In the error trace if you see python3.8 then you need to run
`sudo apt-get install python3.8-gdbm` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ whatever
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in 
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in 
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in 
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm', please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in 
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in 
    import gdbm
ImportError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

remove gdbm first

`apt remove --purge python3-gdbm`

install again

`apt install python3-gdbm`

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

use this command to show which python3-gdbm has been installed:

```
apt search gdbm | grep python
```

if there is python-gdbm installed which is not matched with the python3, such as python3.6-gdbm. You can use this command to remove this missing matched one:

```
sudo apt autoremove python3.6-gdbm
```

Answer (score -2):

sudo apt-get install python3.6-gdbm

this command worked for me finally

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfWsW.png)

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezEdg.png)