# Update Python 3.5 to 3.6 via terminal

Tags: apt, python3

Using Ubuntu 17.04. After update Python 3.5 to 3.6 via terminal according to https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/695385 still showing that version is 3.5.3.

```
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
```

How is this installed?

Comment: How did you update it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/695385

Comment: Then you call it using `python3.6`. `python3` will remain symlinked to `python3.5` and you should keep it that way. Look into virtual environments like Oli wrote in his answer.

Comment: Thanx, now I`ve to find out how to use virtualenv.

Answer (score 20):

### I had the same problem, I did the following instruction to resolve it:

After installing *Python3.6*:

To make `python3` use the new installed *Python 3.6* instead of the default 3.5 release, run following 2 commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Finally, switch between the two Python versions for `python3` via the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Then select the `/usr/bin/python3.6 -- automode` in choices menu, for me that was `0` row.

---

[**Result**]:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.9
```

Or:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Comment: Warning: the gnome-terminal may [fail to launch](https://askubuntu.com/q/880188/727997) after this. It apparently depends on python3 to be 3.5.

Answer (score 10):

How did you upgrade? I suspect you may have a `python3.6` binary *somewhere*.

Generally speaking, you never want to replace `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3` with your own fruity versions. Important parts of Ubuntu require their stable Python environments, and largely speaking, that is incompatible with you mucking around.

That all said, having a `/usr/bin/python3.6` (or `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`, or whatever in your path) would be fine. If you don't want to type all that in each time, you might want to look at `virtualenv` and the various wrapper automation options for it. This has the additional bonus of not threatening your system's `site_packages` with your development work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/695385

Answer (score 5):

Installing and upgrading to Python3.6 requires the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade python3.6
```

Comment: This command installs all the packages. @Sreenath

Comment: But when I do python3 it opens python3.5.. Daah

Answer (score 1):

Use Docker and get the Python image for whatever version you want. It's also easy to update.

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit, for readers with low docker background ? What are we supposed to do with that file ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not specific to `python3.5` to `python3.6` but can be used in general.
Assuming the latest version of python to be `python3.10`

```
# Update apt repo
sudo apt update

# Install new python3.10
sudo apt install python3.10 python3.10-dev -y

# Unlink the python3 command
sudo unlink /usr/bin/python3

# Link to python3.10 binary
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3

# Checking python3 version
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.0+
```

You might face some issue like this with your `apt` commands after installing the newer python version

```
ImportError: No module named apt_pkg
```

For this you can try below commands to update the socket file link

```
# Reinstall python3-apt to create python3.10 apt socket file
sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall

# Link the apt_pkg.so file to python3.10 socket file
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is using PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

And add Python 3.7 to update-alternatives with priority 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this on Ubunutu 16.04:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

Answer (score -2):

Visit https://www.python.org/downloads/source/ to find the latest version.
Check the current stable version before pulling for install.