# Problem when trying to open terminal in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, language-support

Im having troubles at opening the terminal. When I open, an icon appears in the menu bar, but then disappears. Last year something occurred and it was because of the system language.

So what i tried to do this time (with no success) was to change the system language, opening System Settings, and then selecting Language Support but when selecting Language support, it doesn't open.

Someone know a way to fix this problem?

Comment: How do you (try to) open the terminal? Does CTRL-ALT-T work? (That's the keyboard shortcut to open a terminal window.)

Comment: I tried pressing CTRL-ALT-T, but no icon appears on the Launcher. When searching for "Terminal" and clicking it, it appears the icon, but it doesn't initialize (it appears the icon for 10 seconds and then disappears).

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem. The problem was caused because I tried to install python 3.6. I could solve it with the following post: [Gnome terminal will not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start/880191)