# I cannot open the terminal (from launcher, dashboard or other terminals)

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal

When I try to open the Terminal from Gauke Terminal or from XTerm by using

```
   gnome-terminal
```

it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
```

I cannot open terminal from launcher and dashboard, or by using Ctrl+Alt+T.
I tried to reconfigure locale and ~/.profile but that didn't help.

Comment: this may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start

Comment: If you need a terminal right now, try Ctrl+Alt+F3 (either Ctrl+Alt+F2 or Ctrl+Alt+F7 will get you back to the GUI).

Answer (score 0):

There are two important errors in the output, each is at the *bottom* of the two python error stacks:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
```

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Let's figure out which packages aren't working:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py
python3-apt: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py
python3-gi: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py
```

So the **two packages for you to reinstall** are `python3-apt` and `python3-gi`

However, those two packages are *fundamental* to the operation of your Ubuntu system, and it's really unlikely that both failed at once. Something else important is going on that you have not mentioned yet.

Comment: Just a comment. My Windows 10 Ubuntu (WSL) got borked when I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04. Thousands of errors with Python 2 and Python 3 clashing with each other I think. I'll reinstall 16.04 fresh next time I need to boot Windows but it was sure annoying.

Comment: Yeah, I think Microsoft probably needs to do some work to get 18.04 working right.

Comment: @user535733 To format terminal output, paste it into your answer, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor. If you need spacing in between two code blocks that are right next to each other like above, insert `<!-- -->` between them.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex check that edit, looks like you overwrote one of the errors. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user535733 Ahh, good catch. I had accidentally pasted the whole thing with both errors twice.