# Apt saying ALL the packages don't have any installation candidates

Tags: apt, 20.04, mate, software-sources

I have Ubuntu MATE 20.04 installed in my computer. Somehow now apt is absolutely broken. *Every* package doesn't have an installation candidate.

Even worse, I can't download any package at all with Synaptic or aptitude. `/etc/apt/sources.list` seems perfectly fine.

[Synaptic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bSwD.png).

[APT error (in Spanish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCSwB.png)

```
[sudo] password for disablegraphics:  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package fluid is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only  
available from another source  

E: Package 'fluid' has no installation candidate
disablegraphics@disablegraphics:~$ update-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'gi'
```

Sources.list part 1:

[image: Sources.list (part 1)]

Sources.list part 2:

[image: Sources.list (part 2)]

Comment: What did you do between when it worked and now?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140119/every-package-has-no-installation-candidate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Note: The `update-manager` command in the question starts the Software Updater app, and if there are any error messages when running this app it prints them in the terminal. [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1052553/) Please use only `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software and `sudo apt upgrade` to update software until you have solved this problem.

Comment: What happens if you type `sudo apt install aptitude`? If it installs successfully, run `aptitude` without any extra parameters, and see what happens. Assuming it installs successfully, it \*should\* give you some information about what the problem is, and make suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: @TSJNachos117 Installing aptitude won't help to solve this problem because the software sources are incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps if you backup `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and and change all instances of `*.old-releases.ubuntu.com`, with `ubuntu.com` (remove the "*.old-releases" part), and run `sudo apt update`, that might fix your problems. It might also make your problems worse, so make **ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN** you make a backup copy of that file before modifying it. You might also be able to use `software-manager-gtk` or `software-manager-qt` to change mirrors graphically.