# gnome-terminal not working with `Error contructing proxy..`

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.01. About 2 days ago I updated my Ubuntu and restarted as recommended.

But after that, gnome terminal stopped working.

No response when I click the gnome terminal icon.

I tried to execute terminal as below.

```
$/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnone/Terminal/Factory0:
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnmome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

When I checked my python3 I found its version is 3.6.6.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start

Comment: I assume that it solved your issue. So I am raising a flag for your question as the duplicate