# terminal won't launch after installing python 3,7

Tags: gnome, python, gnome-terminal

I have the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start).
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I did a bad job installing Python 3.7.
I tried all that's proposed in the link, but terminal is still not working. I also removed and reinstalled the gnome terminal, but did nothing.

I realized I can't run applications like Startup Disk Creator.

Is there anything else I can try?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This way the upgrade to 3.7 is useless. You should edit the gnome-terminal file:

Open a terminal and issue the following commands:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo nano gnome-terminal
Change #!/usr/bin/python3 to #!/usr/bin/python3.6.
```

This way you can still use the power of 3.7 and solve the issue with the terminal.

Reference: [Terminal not opening up after upgrading python to 3.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132349/terminal-not-opening-up-after-upgrading-python-to-3-7)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i could not launch gnome-terminal and gnome-tweak-tool after installing Python 3.7.
I fixed this by changing python3 point config with below command.

`sudo update-alternatives --config python3`

Choose suitable number to return your default python3,this is 3.6 in my case.
I guest that gnome-terminal cant launch with python 3.7.

Hope this can help you!