# Terminal not opening up after upgrading python to 3.7

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, python3

I have upgraded python to version 3.7 and now my terminal is not opening up.

I followed this post https://jcutrer.com/linux/upgrade-python37-ubuntu1810

Commands I ran are as follows,

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Entered 2 for python3.7

I can't open terminal and run commands.

My ubuntu version is, Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1246153/895417

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This way the upgrade to 3.7 is useless.
You should edit the `gnome-terminal` file:

Open a tty shell with Ctrl+Alt+F3(F2 to close it). Login with your credentials and issue the following command:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Change `#!/usr/bin/python3` to `#!/usr/bin/python3.6`.

This way you can still use the power of 3.7 and solve the issue with the terminal.

Comment: Will this change be overriden when gnome-terminal is updated in the future?

Comment: These are terminal commands. How am I supposed to enter these if terminal will not open?

Comment: @crashspringfield `xterm` should be available. Or you can switch to a TTY

Comment: this answer worked for me, basically updating `gnome-terminal`  to import a new library https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352723/2011798

Comment: This fix did not work for Python 3.10 for me. I had to use Python3.8 instead.

Answer (score 17):

I ran the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Entered 1

I got my terminal back.

Still wonder why it wasn't working with python3.7.1 though.

To get access to command line if terminal is not opening up try the below shortcuts to run commands on a virtual terminal or refer to [how-to-access-bash-without-a-terminal-emulator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636691/how-to-access-bash-without-a-terminal-emulator)

`Ctrl+Alt+(F1` through `F4` at least, maybe up to `F6`) run a terminal interface on the virtual consoles. Once there, to get back to the GUI, use `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.

Comment: Answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/880188/415708) may help explain this.

Comment: fixing the gnome-terminal seems much better. I'd suggest to remove this answer and accept the one that fixes the terminal.