# Terminal on Ubuntu20 does not start anymore after installing Python 3.7

Tags: python3

looks I have chicken and egg problem. I have updated Python3 to 3.7 on Ubuntu 20.04
The terminal does not start anymore. I have read this thread: [Terminal not opening up after upgrading python to 3.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132349/terminal-not-opening-up-after-upgrading-python-to-3-7)

Question is: how do I open a terminal (this is my problem) to configure *gnome-terminal* to fix the problem as suggested there?
I have tried to change the file *gnome-terminal* using the GUI but I do not have rights to save.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try text mode login by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F4 (or F5)?

Comment: You say you updated Python 3 to 3.7.  Did you do that by installing overtop Pyrthon 3.8 installed on the system by default?  Because that is going to break *everything* on the system (which is EXACTLY why you do NOT touch the system version of Python!)

Comment: I switched back to Python3.8 from tty and I got the terminal back. To your question @ThomasWard, original version was Python3.8, I have installed Python3.7 too. I needed for compatibility with a version of Spark!

Comment: @toto' You should keep in mind that changing your system Python version and **downgrading** it is dangerous, and will break your system.  Same for upgrading the version.  Since 3.8 is the version of Python on system, and 3.7 is not, you really should not touch python 3.8 on the system, it'll break things.  You can spin up a separate venv with something like `pyenv` and then have your Spark client executed after creating a 3.7 versioned environment in userspace.  Saves your headache of running Spark and revising the core system - this is why you don't edit system libs though without knowledge.