I lost my gnome terminal after down grading to python 3.10. Ubuntu 24.01 lts in order to install rasa ai
I tried 3 times reinstall and it happened every time. is that a known problem? Rasa will not install with python 3.12 As long as the terminal is open after installing rasa I can use it but once closed it never reopens. Maybe I should change back to python 3.12 after rasa is up and running and before exiting the terminal? is this a known issue?

You've not provided any valid Ubuntu product/release details; as there was no Ubuntu release in 2024-January (24.01). If you change the default python3 version you'll of course lose access to system tools that rely on python3 for operation (them stopping to work is a good thing, the alternative is they don't work correctly due to version change as this can lead to corruption). You notice the change less on server systems, but you cannot change the default python3 version if using a GUI system without loads of your system not working or risking corruption. Don't do it.

Maybe useful is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132349/terminal-not-opening-up-after-upgrading-python-to-3-7  but be aware of the risks on your unstated OS (likely Ubuntu 24.10 but you don't mention that possibly due to typo)

Sorry ubuntu 24.04.1LTS

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I installed a dual boot ubuntu 24.04.1LTS on my machine in order to get rasa ai platform as it works best on linux. the ubuntu installed with python 3.12, When I went on to instal the rasa it was not compatible wit hpython 3.12 so i had to down grade to python 3.10 in order to install rasa.

I was able to install and verify rasa this way. unfortunately after i closed the gnome terminal it never launched again. My questions are : is it a known issue with a remedy? a logical solution would be to upgrade the python back to 3.12 after Rasa is installed but before i close the terminal. is it doable? Has it been done? I'm still not sure how this update of the python back to 3.12 will affect my rasa ai operation..

Changing python version in Ubuntu is like replacing one person's heart with another person's. It is known that it destroys Ubuntu. It is not an issue of Ubuntu because python is an integral part of it, and is not supposed to be removed. If you are unable to change python version, you will have to reinstall. In future, never replace the default python version. Instead, use virtual environments for different python versions.

Thank you. I will try to do just that- change back. I think it gives me a choice of python versions installed -I just have to dig out the command

Sorry I'm not a coder so I will be plain: here are the steps that did not and did work so far
changing back to python312 did work for ubuntu but took out rasa. I had to create virtual environment for Rasa with the python 3.10 version in order for both to work. now my ubuntu has 3.12.xx but my rasa keeps 3.10.xx So far so good here is the command to create a separate environment with python 3.10

python3.10 -m venv rasa_env -
maybe that will help someone- it took some research ;-)

