# I cannot open gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I have an Intel Core i7 CPU with a GeForce RTX 2070.

I am using a new lab computer. Whenever I push on the terminal applet, I see the clock icon running, then nothing. The only thing I had done was installed Chrome. I read that installing Chrome may have been the issue, so I uninstalled the application and reset the computer. However, I still cannot access the terminal.

I do not have much experience with Linux, so feel free to ask if you need any more info.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+t or Alt+F2 and run `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: @PabloA ctrl+alt+t does nothing. And nothing happens when I run that command after pressing alt+f2. Any ideas?

Comment: Try others: `uxterm`, `xterm`, `x-terminal-emulator` (`terminator`), or with Ctrl + Alt + F4 (virtual console) and read the logs (`journalctl -xe`).

Comment: I got it working with xterm. That’s good at least. Do you know why terminal isn’t working though? Seems kinda concerning.

Comment: I don't know. Run `gnome-terminal` from xterm and see what happen (something to stdout/stderr?). Check the logs with `journalctl`. Might be useful if you add the output of `inxi -SG -! 31 -y 80`.

Comment: I got "ImportError: cannot import name '-gi' from 'gi'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99023/discussion-between-spencer-kraisler-and-pablo-a).

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem might be because you are using a "new lab computer" and who knows what they've cooked up in the lab?

Try this for starters:

```
$ apt list | grep gnome-terminal

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gnome-terminal/xenial,now 3.18.3-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-terminal-data/xenial,xenial,now 3.18.3-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

If it doesn't say "`[installed]`" at the end of the last two lines then let's install it with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

Hopefully the problem is as simple to fix as that...

Reply to comment:

Sounds like you need to use:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Source: [Gnome terminal will not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and it seems both are installed. However when I type "gnome-terminal" in xterm, I get "Import Error: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi'

Comment: @SpencerKraisler I replied to your comment within the answer. If this works we will probably close your question as a duplicate of the Q&A I linked in this revision.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler On second sober thought that answer was for 16.04. There is a new answer that says: "'sudo update-alternatives --config python3'" which may work better for your 18.04. Sorry can't say for sure but examine all the answers there please.