# Can't Access Terminal

Tags: command-line, python

I was clumsily trying to update python on my system. My terminal will no longer open, although I'm thankfully still able to use xterm.

I say clumsily because I was trying to set python for my user and was using `sudo`, thereby setting it systemwide without realizing it.

Here's a good symptom of my problem before I keep making it worse:

```
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:!$ sudo python --version
Python 3.8.1
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:!$ python --version
Python 3.7.2
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:!$ lsb_release -a
bash: /usr/bin/lsb_release: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT**

Per the comments, here is my Traceback from running gnome-terminal in xterm. None of the answers suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start/) resolved the circular import.

````
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:!$ gnome-terminal
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/gone-terminal", line 9, in <module>
  from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  from . import_gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)```
````

Comment: What is your OS? Changing default python to python 3.x is a poor idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gnome terminal will not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start)

Comment: @Pilot6 It resolved the lsb_release issue. I included the terminal output when running `gnome-terminal`

Comment: I also tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/999978/483171), but the files 36m already existed.