# Can not open terminal in a normal way on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, gnome, python, gnome-terminal, 20.04

I have updated my computer from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. During the update, may be I accidentally deleted some file when some pop-up appeared.
I accepted this [ubuntu ask to replace config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAlx7.png). And chose remove [ubuntu ask for remove obsolete package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f7Og.png)
I looked at the list of the file but it's too strange and the OS tells me that they are old.

When I am on the new OS, I cannot open terminal by clicking the icon or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. I can only open it by clicking 'open in terminal' in nautilus. I tried opening terminal by typing `gnome-terminal` but there's an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
```

I searched and found this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start) on askubuntu. I followed the accepted answer but that didn't help. I also tried the second best answer and the result is the same. I think its because I am missing those `_gi.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and `_gi_cairo.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` files. I have already installed python3.6 and python3.5 ?

Someone in the comment suggests that `apt_pkg` is missing. And I ran `sudo apt-get update` to check and found an error message: `ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`.

Again I started searching on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i). I tried some solutions and realized the folder `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/` contains only `_gi_cairo.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and `_gi_cairo.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` files. So I coppied it into `apt_pkg`. Now, the error from `apt-get update` is resolved, however I still cannot open terminal in both the earlier methods I described.

I have tried every solution I can find on stackoverflow but it still won't help. The last solution I can think of is reinstalling the OS. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you happened to remember anything useful about the "some file" you deleted, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm only too eager to upgrade. I have add 2 images' link but because I'm new to ask ubuntu, I can't post image.

Comment: Reviewers: OP stated in a comment on the answer that they reinstalled...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and error message with 20.04. I traced it to the python version. The 20.04 upgrade installs python 3.8. I needed python 3.7 as well and had set update-alternatives to 3.7. Setting back to 3.8 fixed this issue.

Not sure if that helps here.

Comment: I just reinstalled my ubuntu a few minutes ago. ANW, thanks for the solution, hope this's helpful to others.