# Python 3.10.2 installation breaks Terminal?

Tags: 20.04, python, gnome-terminal

So I just installed Python 3.10.2 and now I cannot open the Terminal application anymore. Ctrl+alt+t does not work either, and clicking on the application does absolutely nothing.

I have to admit, I did see a warning saying that making 3.10 the default python version might break some applications but I checked the dependencies and did not see anything that would make me suspect something like this happening. What can I do now?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There are many sad stories on this site from people who broke their systems by messing with python. Try searching the site for the answers they already received.

Comment: Yes it does break the terminal and a whole lot of things. Now you will have to reinstall ubuntu (that is the simplest way to fix). You can install additional versions of python from the deadsnakes PPA, or use anaconda to set up python in an isolated environment. But replacing the default python version will definitely break Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications) (if this answer does not work for you, reinstall Ubuntu. One you have reinstalled Ubuntu, you can follow this answer to simultaneously install multiple versions of python. https://askubuntu.com/q/682869/124466)

Comment: You BROKE it time to re install from scratch. DO NOT mess with Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gnome terminal will not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start)

Comment: Had the same issue, this solution seems to work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600059/ubuntu-terminal-wont-launch

Answer (score 1):

Change the default Python version to what it was *before* you changed to v. 3.10.2. Several core functions of Ubuntu are dependent on (if I remember correctly) a form of Python 3.8. If you cannot get the default version working properly, copy any file system info and re-install the OS.

Comment: It seems that OP cannot access terminal. How would they change the python version? Maybe add some information about opening a virtual at TTY3.

Comment: I have the same impression. I had to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 in order to get Python 3.10, and, actually, I started deploying Debian 11.6, which has no such problem, and Python 3.9