# Updating to python 3.8 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python

I am updating python to 3.8. After following some tutorials when I type:

```
python --version
```

I get

```
Python 3.7.4
```

If I type:

```
python3.8 --version
```

I get

```
Python 3.8.12
```

How can I get the python --version to say that I am using 3.8 ??

Comment: Which OS & version? Can you give us more details about "some tutorial"?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. The tutorials: https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2019-12/how-to-install-python38-on-ubuntu/
and 
https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Answer (score 4):

When you need python 3.8, call it with `python3.8`.

---

You should not change the default `python3.6` in Ubuntu 18.04. Otherwise, you may experience a lot of problems.

Run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

And choose `python3.6`. You can also choose 3.8 here (at your own risk), but it may lead to nasty issues like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1391322/124466).

Comment: Perhaps add how the user can then use python 3.8

Comment: @vanadium It's already in the answer.

Comment: All right, first sentence!