# gnome-terminal installed but not opening

Tags: gnome-terminal

I tried to install the newest version of Python in my Ubuntu laptop. When I finished installing it, I realized that my Terminal and some other apps were gone. They were not among my favorites where I had them and I searched for them and they were gone.

I restarted my laptop to see if that fixed the problem. When it turned on, it automatically went to tty terminal.

I searched online and I found [this forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=818443) so I run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-terminal
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

However, I got:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
update-notifier-common
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched online and I tried running all solutions in [this article](https://www.tecmint.com/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-in-ubuntu/) one by one:

```
sudo apt remove --purge update-notifier-common
```

Once I did this, the Sub-process error disappeared and I (apparently) was able to install the Terminal again, but now it does not open.

Again, in the tty terminal I run:

```
gnome-terminal --version
```

And it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

For this issue I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start) from 7 years ago. Some of the solutions given there are not recommended by other users, so I avoided them. From this thread, I tried the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and it said:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python 3
```

At this point, I don't know what else to do. The last thread seems a bit outdated. Can anyone help me with some updated solutions? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it did not help. I even removed and reinstalled python3, which made my desktop GUI disappear, and I had to reinstall it. Once I reinstalled it, I got the error that I got at the beginning: 
Errors were encountered while processing:
update-notifier-common
update-notifier
ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop-minimal
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your system missing the `gi.repository` python module. You need to install it.

```
sudo apt install python3-gi
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this first, but it did not work. Still the same issue, the terminal loads for a while and then just stop responding.