# How to install Python 3.6 in virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 which comes with python 2.7 and python 3.5 pre-installed. I am currently working on a project where it requires to install python 3.6 and some additional packages. I have searched the Internet but i couldn't manage to get the comprehensive tutorial steps where I could follow. Please help me.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered by @edwinksl here: https://askubuntu.com/a/865569

The 3.6 version of Python doesn't seem to have been added to the official repositories for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However there are others that have created repositories for it, among them J Fernyhough. You can add and install Python 3.6 via his repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Comment: I did that but when I run `python3` after that, I still run python 3.5 as earlier.

Comment: You need to run it using `python3.6`. Both version will be installed on your machine and `python3` is still aliasing `python3.5` (or might actually be the command, I don't know).