# installing python fails with permission denied (using sudo make install)

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, permissions, sudo, python3

I tried to install Python 3.6 using this tutorial: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming#run-python-os on ubuntu 14.04.

Running

```
$ ./configure
```

and

```
$ make
```

went fine. Running

```
$ sudo make install
```

gives me the following errors:

```
make: stat: GNUmakefile: Permission denied
make: stat: makefile: Permission denied
make: stat: Makefile: Permission denied
make: stat: install: Permission denied
make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop.
```

I know Python 3.6 is not installable via apt-get for ubuntu 14.04 yet, but this problem seems to me to be unrelated to incompatibility. Can someone help me with the installation?

Comment: Python 3.6 is installable with `apt-get` for Ubuntu 14.04; see https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/15003.

Comment: Thanks. For others like me who haven't worked with PPAs yet: [what are PPAs and are they save?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for)