# What with Python 3.6?

Tags: 17.04, python3

Can anyone tell why Python 3.6 is not available in Zesty? Whenever I try to update it, the latest is 3.5.3. Is there any problem with 3.6, or they are waiting for 3.7?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926513/why-is-python-3-6-not-available-via-official-ubuntu-repositories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3.6 **is** available in Ubuntu 17.04, yet it's not the default, see [the package python3.6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/python3.6).

Why not make it default then? See [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-February/147347.html) for the full story.

When will it be default? The latter source says:

> I plan for 18.04 LTS to ship only Python 3.6

If you want to install Python 3.6 in Zesty, do

```
sudo apt install python3.6
```

and run it via

```
python3.6
```

Comment: Just `python3.6` would be enough to run it, no need for the full path usually.

Comment: Thank you! How extremely intuitive it was. The batteries were included - but one has to remember to plug them in :)