# Help Installing Python on Ubuntu

Tags: 17.04, python-2.7

I'm attempting to install both the last version of python 2 which is currently 2.7.14 according to the site, and the latest for v3, even though I don't really need it. (Just to see if I can get any version of python to work)

I only truly need python 2 in order to run an old python program on Ubuntu.

I recently tried installing both versions in the following manner, first:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

After python 2 seems installed, I tried checking the version:

```
python -V
```

However, this input returns:

```
-bash: python: command not found
```

Same with python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

I get another negative output when checking for the version.

```
-bash: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
```

It seems like both versions don't fully install.

I must add an important fact though, the reason why I can't get to install and use any python version on my Ubuntu system is provably because I already removed python 3 previously in this doubtfull manner:

```
sudo apt purge python3.5-minimal
```

Since:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3.5
```

Wasn't doing the job for the removal of python 3 (It still fully functioned).
I feel like I may have deleted something important while trying to propperly re-install python on my sistem.

Why I installed python 3 (Which I did get to work) if all I really need is python 2? The answer is, I didn't know I needed python 2 in order to run this python program, so I thought installing the latest version would be the wisest thing to do. However the developer informed me that the program can only run with python 2 (Once I found out I couldn't run it on 3). So I thought the best thing would be to remove python 3 entirely and install 2 instead, however this hasn't gone so well.

Could I get some orientation on how to propperly fix this mess and install python 2? All I really need is python 2 for executing a program from that version.

Specifications:

```
Ubuntu version: 17.04
Desired python version: 2.7.14 (Currently at the time of writing this is 
latest)
```

If you find my issue is not concise enough, please ask. I'll try my best at expanding the details (By editing + commenting).

Comment: the double hyphen is for full word options (in this case `python --version`), in your case, you should be typing `python -V`.

Comment: Well, python3 is installed by default, as many default tools and apps use it. You should not remove it. You need the `python-minimal` package installed for /usr/bin/python. You likely don't really need 2.7.14 for an _old_ program, and the version in current 17.04 will do fine. However, 2.7.14 is in 17.10, which will be released next month, which you should upgrade to from 17.04 (as it will be EOL in 3 months after 17.10 is released).

Comment: @S.Ith Corrected typo. The issue is still the same.

Comment: @dobey I thought so... So I basically removed something which was already included. But I removed it so deeply it broke any further installation. Do I need to reinstall "python-minimal" with sudo-apt get?

Comment: I think you just need to install `python` and `python3`. I also think you think you need a later version of _python_ than you actually need. You really only need the absolute latest version in some extreme extenuating circumstances, which your old program likely doesn't meet.

Comment: I just did a clean install and upgrade of ubuntu 17.04 in a VM, and after retracing all of your steps, python 2.7.13 works ok (the version you can download using the repos). When you did the `apt-get remove`, you uninstalled a lot of packages, and the number grew up after the `apt-get purge`, though both `remove` and `purge`, leave dependencies installed with the package on installation time untouched. So it must be something else. Reinstalling python 2.7.13 should do the trick through `apt install`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install python 2:

```
sudo apt install python
```

To install python 3:

```
sudo apt install python3
```

To see python version just start python

```
python
```

for python2

```
python3
```

for python3

You can also use:

```
python --version
```

or

```
python3 --version
```

To install the latest version, download it, unzip it and
install primary versions of python (the one you want by default) with:

```
sudo make install
```

and install secondary versions with:

```
sudo make altinstall
```

You can also follow this answer: [How do I install Python 3.6 using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get#865569)

Comment: Looks like with your command I successfully installed python 2. All that's different from your command is that it's just "apt" instead of "apt-get"

Comment: the latest versions usually don't come with the distribution, if you need them I think you have to install from source.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include installation from source.

Comment: I consider your answer correct. Because it basically solved my problem. (Somehow)
Thanks! :)