# How to install Python 3.6 in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS without root privilege ?

Tags: python3

I don't have sudo rights to a machine but I have to install Python 3.6 in it.

Comment: If you have the building dependencies already installed, you could try `pyenv`, as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/865644/367990

Comment: pyenv is not installed.

Comment: No, pyenv is a script you can get from GitHub. You can download and run that as a user, but it requires some tools (like the `build-essential` package) and development packages to be installed on your system already. Please read through the linked answer.

Comment: I cant run pyenv as curl is not installed in the system. Plus there is no way to install the tools required by pyenv.

Comment: You could consider [Anaconda python](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) which iirc installs into your home directory by default