# How do I install Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, python3

I have several systems. Some are 16.04 mini-servers and I cannot update the OS yet. The others have been updated to Ubuntu 18.04. (The 18.04 version I used has Python 3.6.5 on it).

Answer (score 7):

Currently there is no trusted PPA containing python 3.7, so you will have to build it yourself.
Download desired version and follow the instruction on this [documentation page.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html)

It should be as easy as:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Update:
Thank you to C14L, also now it is on doc page.
`make install` can overwrite or masquerade the python3 binary. `make altinstall` is therefore recommended instead of `make install` since it only installs exec_prefix/bin/pythonversion

```
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: Not really, the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has it.

Comment: If you say it is secure I would like to update the answer

Comment: Well, it’s always the [matter of trust](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/250300) but deadsnakes is the de-facto standard for Python AFAIK. See the [answer I linked before](https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/250300) currently having 373 upvotes.

Comment: hey, just to be sure linked answer will work for 3.7 with appropriate edits?

Comment: _You_ should check it yourself if you want that in your answer. :-) However, I find OK to keep your current answer together with my previous comment.

Comment: Just to confirm: deadsnakes does have the 3.7 version. I also tested it minimally and it seems to work

Comment: From the linked page: *Warning `make install` can overwrite or masquerade the python3 binary. `make altinstall` is therefore recommended ...*

Comment: WARNING for 16.04 users: this works but it breaks several things in your system, including the terminal from GUI (fortunately Atl-Ctrl-F1 still work to repair the mess). make altinstall does not break your system right away but it will if you make 3.7 the default alternative.