# Install python 3.7 with the 3.5 version already installed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python3, ipython

I almost broke my Ubuntu installation trying to install python 3.7 from the source using `checkinstall`.
My question is how to install python 3.7 and it's equivalent ipython   alongside with python 3.5 without breaking everything related to the native python installation ?

Comment: This question has info about installing Python 3.6 using APT or pyenv: [How do I install Python 3.6 using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/q/865554/301745) For installing 3.7, the instructions should be virtually identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to double check what are the currents installed version using the following commands
`python --version`  and/or `python3 --version`

The we make sure that the latest version of Debian is installed before the python installation.

A simple `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` followed by rebooting the computer will do.

Then, in order to verify the key signature of the python tar file we need to install DirMngr if it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install  dirmngr
```

After that we can retrieve the OpenPGP Public Keys from [the python downnload page](https://www.python.org/downloads) and pass it out to the following command line:

```
gpg --recv-key AA65421D
```

and use it to verify the downloaded version

```
gpg --verify Python-3.6.4.tar.xz.asc
```

(3.6.4  can be changed for the specific version downloaded from python website)

From here, we copy our tar file to src folder

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads//Python-3.6.4.tar.xz /usr/src/
```

And we cd to the src folder and we untar the archive

```
cd /usr/src/ && sudo tar -xf Python-3.6.4.tar.xz
```

The following dependencies may be needed before compiling

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall zlib1g zlib1g-dev openssl
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.5
```

The next step is to configure and install using altinstall to avoid versions conflict and to break program already running with the previous python version

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

To run the 3.7 version you can simply use python3.7 to launch the interpreter and to install the equivalent ipython you can use this command

`python3.7 -m pip install ipython`