# Python 3.6 IDLE Not Downloading

Tags: python

```
sudo apt-get install idle-python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 idle-python3.6 : Depends: python3-tk but it is not installable
              Depends: python3.6-tk but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

--

I'm just trying to follow what the tutorial tells me to do, I don't have much knowledge of Ubuntu, as I just switched from Win10.

TYIA

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get)

Comment: You should not need any tutorial. Undo everything you did: Uninstall everything you installed, delete the non-Ubuntu sources you added. IDLE can be installed with a single apt command once you have undone the unnecessary changes you made.