# Broke Python Whilst Trying to Upgrade 3.8 to 3.9

Tags: python3

Here is what happened; I tried to upgrade python3.8 to 3.9; my goal was to Install python3.9 and then force my system to start using 3.9 instead of the current 3.8.

Then I found ths[How to Upgrade to Python3.9](https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-9-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

Ignorantly without reading the comments, I jumped into my terminal and started executing the install and update-alternatives commands; at the end of the article; I discovered that I wrote a small python program and discovered that I could not run it.

That was when I decided to go through the comments, and discovered that some dependencies were missing; having tried to install dist-utils for 3.9; my system did not allow any install, kept saying it's available or something so I ignored and decided to quickly go back to my 3.8 having read some articles here warning against messing with default python installations.

Initially, my fear was that I have broken the default python installation; even though I never attempted removing it, so I decided to switch back to the old 3.8 I had working well.

I did was simply following the same article which gave room for switching between the python versions and switched back to 3.8; now it appears I'm fine.

My question is how to setup the installed 3.9 so that I can have it function properly?

Comment: You need to set up a python environment. Don't change the installed version of python on your system.  You will break all of the software that requires the version in repositories for your Ubuntu release. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/865644

Comment: Thanks, I have already done that by using built-in venv module and then Conda. trying to install Anaconda Navigator now.