# Software Updater did nothing when clicked upgrade (to 20.04 from 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

I installed the latest 18.04 updates with Software Updater and hit upgrade (to go to 20.04 from 18.04) and nothing happened.  According to Synaptic, I have no broken packages.

I would like to stick with the GUI upgrade process rather than the command line.

I don't know if this is related, but I recently uninstalled openssl1.0.2 because 1.1.1 was also installed and the 1.0.2 headers were preventing me from compiling Python3.10. This apparently broke the calculator and system monitor apps - which is the main reason I'm trying to upgrade.

Comment: Sounds like a pickle - there are no errors to work with, and you don't want to use the terminal. What can we do for you anyway?

Comment: Release upgrades don't usually solve preexisting problems and can actually compound them.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) because instead of providing actionable details and asking a question about your real problem, you are asking how to achieve a proposed solution that probably won't actually solve your real problem.  I suggest that you ask about and provide details about the actual problem.

Comment: It's possible that installing a different version of python broke your system.  This is because several aspects of Ubuntu rely on python and the version of python on your release is expected by other packages in your release. For this reason, it's not recommended that you change the installed version of python. You can and should use a separate environment if you need a particular python version for some task or project.

Comment: I didn't use apt or Synaptic to install a new system version of python to avoid a system conflict (>which python3 still shows the python 3.6.9 version in /usr/bin as it did previously).  I used altinstall which put Python3.10 in /usr/local/bin and right now I reference it as python3.10 at the command line.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference how you installed it.  See: https://askubuntu.com/a/865644

Comment: I guess I don't know what to try next.  I thought installing 20.04 would clear up any lingering openssl issues.  Would it?  If so, I could try the command line update process and see if I see any errors I can fix.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue concerned nvidia drivers.  While newish ones were installed, there was a piece of an older version which did not get removed automatically.  So the updater wouldn't move forward because it said this older version needed to be updated.  By removing this piece of an older version I was able to update.